# smtp Mailer function

Tags: php, smtp

I am new to smtp mailer functionality, Can I use any email address as SMTP user field like following,

```
            $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
            $config['smtp_user']    = 'myname@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass']    = 'password;';
            $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
            $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 
            $config['validation'] = TRUE;
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. The E-Mail address should be one that is served by the same server you send the E-Mail from.

Otherwise, spam filters will block the E-Mail, even if your SMTP server accepts it (which it shouldn't).

If you need to use an E-Mail address from a different domain, use `reply-to`.